# HttpSession reinit by Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, tomcat, httpsession

I develop a website in Java und Tomcat 7.0.53, with Authentification from User.
When authenticated, the user is saved in the HttpSession.
Under firefox, everything works fine. But under Chrome, it seems that the session is reinitialized after a short while : I reload several times the same page, then it disconnects alone.
I put a timeout of 36000-> about one hour, but no change.
I installed Chrome and tested just after, so there is no problem of configuration.

Can everyone help?
Thanks a lot

Niko

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the answer on my own... and it is everything but trivial!
Google Chrome expect a favicon to not delete the session...
I found the solution here.
http://tutorial4java.blogspot.de/2012/07/session-problem-in-google-chrome.html

Comment: Edit : It worked for a while... but not anymore. I have this time absolutely no idea why this. Each time I reload the page, this erases my session's cookie. Please help me to solve it (A way to find where the problem comes from could be a good start.)
Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you find the solution? Please let me know if you have done this?